# Simplest way to "encrypt" string with another string key?

Tags: javascript, ruby, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I want to encrypt an input and get an encrypted output, by supplying my own key.

The key points here (which differentiate me from post SO posts and things i've googled so far)

1. I need to encrypt/decrypt between ruby and javascript, so ideally a library which belongs to both
2. **SIMPLICITY OVER SECURITY.** This is the main differentiator... I've tried looking at openSSL tutorials and they're quite advanced. I literally just need to encrypt a string, this doesn't have anything to do with security or sensitive info, as obviously in that case you would use proper encryption. For this I just need to obscure something that isn't very important.

Comment: Would Caesar cipher be good enough for your needs? :)

Comment: So what are you asking? You're going to need to choose an encryption algorithm, and then write that (or find a written version) in your chosen language.

Comment: You don't need a library that works with both ruby and javascript. You just need to pick an encryption standard such as RSA or Triple Des. Then you can get an appropriate library for both.

Comment: It should also be noted that this question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Questions intended to resolve a specific programming problem that have only one correct answer are for Stack Overflow. A "specific programming problem" can be defined as a problem that exists in code and that can be resolved with correct code (or cannot be resolved at all). These questions are normally language-specific.

Comment: @ShaneNal my question is what algorithm can I use that is simple? There are literally hundreds, and all the ones I googled are more advanced than what I need.

Comment: Just use the classic HMAC. Ruby: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/HMAC.html and JavaScript: https://caligatio.github.io/jsSHA/

Comment: @medik perfect answer thanks so much

Comment: @medik: huh? HMAC is a hash, isn't it?

Comment: I think he means the HMAC module, which does what I need:

Comment: @Tallboy: I thought you need to be able to decrypt stuff.

Comment: Hm I do, the decryption will be done on the ruby side. I'm looking through the module now to see how thats possible

Comment: @Tallboy: yeah well, with hmac (and other hashing functions) that's impossible

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can I just use XOR or something?

Comment: @Tallboy: totally. If encryption strengh is not a concern (which you stated it isn't)

Comment: Just ROT13 if you don't care about security. If you *do* care, OpenSSL can be a bit cantankerous to work with, but it has support for public and private keys.

Comment: if security's not a concern what's the point of encrypting it at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a basic [XOR cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) in Ruby:

```
key = 'private_key'

def xor_cypher(text, key)
  text.each_byte.zip(key.each_byte.cycle).map { |a, b| (a ^ b).chr }.join
end

p xor_cypher('This is my secret message', key)
# "$\x1A\x00\x05A\x1D\x16\x7F\x06\x1CY\x03\x17\n\x04\x04\x00E2\x0E\x16\n\x11\x15\f"
p xor_cypher("$\x1A\x00\x05A\x1D\x16\x7F\x06\x1CY\x03\x17\n\x04\x04\x00E2\x0E\x16\n\x11\x15\f", key)
# "This is my secret message"
```

It shouldn't be too hard to write the same in JS.

It would be a good idea to use a long, random binary key (not just usual alpha characters) and binary data as well.

If not, you might compress the data first and encrypt it later.

Comment: I got that much but I couldn't figure out how to convert it to hex, or with normal characters.

Answer (score -3):

Just use the classic HMAC. [Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/HMAC.h%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Btml) and [JavaScript](http://caligatio.github.io/jsSHA).

(Edited from an accepted comment.)

Comment: Would you be so kind and show how to "decrypt" something that went through HMAC?

Comment: If this is not a security issue, Tallboy could just compare the results of encryption. If this does not make sense, cipher might be what the author is looking for.

Comment: I need to decrypt the value back out, providing the original string key

Comment: In such a case I recommend some simple cipher, it's really easy and fun to implement.

Comment: This is a hash, not an encryption method.

Comment: I'd like to save space as well, if possible. I dont want it to be 1:1 (again, if possible)

Comment: I was under the impression sometimes an encrypted message could sometimes be less than the original message, I guess I am mistaken